# Nvidia Quadro P2000 and Quadro K5000 compatibility with tensorflow 2.x version

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nvidia, compatibility

I have Nvidia Quadro P2000 and Quadro K5000 on my computer and I've been trying to use them to run TensorFlow-GPU, but so far TensorFlow doesn't recognize them. I've updated the GPU drivers, installed Cuda toolkit 10.1 and 11, neither one worked.

I was wondering if these two GPUs are not compatible at all with Tensorflow 2.x. I've used Quadro P2000 before, with Tensorflow 1.13, however, I developed my code using Tensorflow 2.x so Keras and Tensorflow are merged, it would be a headache to write everything from scratch based on Tensorflow.1.13.

if they are compatible, what might be the issue?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) above mentioned GPU's are CUDA enabled cards. Are you using `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` to recognize them? If there are any incompatibility between versions of Tensorflow, CUDA and cuDNN it won't recognize GPU.You can check tested build configuration [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just set-up my Quadro K5000 to work with tensorflow 2.1 (on Windows 10). It only worked for me with version 2.0 and 2.1; my understanding is that K5000 compute capability is too low for later versions - see https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus for the list of compute capability per cards.
You may want to try with tensorflow 2.0 or 2.1